# PHP display tree in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a html tree with the html tag ul and li. I am getting the information with a recursive method and is displayed accordingly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 9
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 10
                                                )
                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 11
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 7
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 8
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

This is my array and i walk through in a recursive method to make it ident correctly using ul and li tags. but i cant seems to make it work perfectly :P Any ideas of what i am doing wrong? Here is the method i use:

```
public function test($data){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if(isset($row['id'])){
            echo '<li>' . $row['id'] . '</li>';
        }else{
            $this->test($row);
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: How does it look now? *cant seems to make it work perfectly* isn't really helpful.

Comment: try to echo the '<li>' tag before and after 'if' statement

Comment: Why is it not correctly? What is the problem?

Comment: The ul list is not build correctly. The indents are not the same as the array of data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if this indents perfectly or not (it's been a long time), but I use this a lot:

```
function pre($data)
{
    return '<pre>'.var_export($data, true).'</pre>';
}

echo pre("your data here");
```

The pre tag makes sure the browser doesn't ignore line breaks, tabs, and other stuff.

Answer (score -2):

The `var_dump()` function could not do what you want ? (`var_dump($myArray);`)